# Laravel consoletv/charts v 6.0 - Get count per day and per Item name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-charts

How do i query to make total count per day based on a name or an id?

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Facebook |
| 2 | Twitter |
| 3 | Reddit |

| id | page_id | social_id | visited_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-03-27 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2021-03-27 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2021-03-27 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 2021-03-27 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | 2021-03-27 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 2021-03-27 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 2021-03-28 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 | 2021-03-28 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 | 2021-03-28 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 | 2021-03-28 |
| 11 | 1 | 3 | 2021-03-28 |
| 12 | 1 | 3 | 2021-03-28 |

With the following query i get count of click on all social anchors per day, but i want to show in the chart also which social anchor has been clicked on that day.

```
$social_stats= Social::join('social_statistics', 'social_statistics.social_id','socials.id')
                   ->select( array(
                                   'social_statistics.visited_at as visited_at',
                                    DB::raw('count(*) as count'),
                                  )
                           )
                   ->orderBy('visited_at')
                   ->groupBy('visited_at')
                   ->pluck('count','visited_at')
                   ->all();
```

Need to render a Chart that shows by day the count of click on different social.

```
    $social_bar_chart = new SocialBarChart;


    $visited_at = collect(array_keys($this->social_bar));


    $social_bar_labels = $visited_at->map(function ($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date)->format('d/m');
    })->toArray();



    $social_bar_chart->labels($social_bar_labels)
                      ->dataset('Social Count', 'bar', array_values($this->social_bar))
                      ->options([
                        'tooltip' =>['show' => true],
                        'backgroundColor' => '#54a0ff',
                    ]);
```

Comment: have you tried groupBy with social_id?

Comment: No that wasn't the problem, first time i use consoletv package. i solved by changing the query and get all the data i needed into an array and then pass them to the chart with a loop. Maybe not the best solution, but it works fine for now